# Convert array(object?) to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert this array into a string but it gives me the error:

`Object [object Array] has no method 'split'`

I am converting to a string, so it shouldn't have that problem, I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

My code is:

```
function preSubmit(){
    var optionTexts = [];
    $("section").each(function(){
        var h2 = $(this).find("h2").text();
        optionTexts.push(h2);
        $("ol li", this).each(function() { optionTexts.push($(this).text()); });
    });
    var optionTextString = optionTexts.toString();
    var splitText = optionTextString.split(",");
    console.log(splitText);
    return splitText;
}
```

The returned value of `typeof splitText` gives me [object Array], but I expect `string`.

Comment: If you want a string and you have a string, why are you splitting it back into an array? That's what `split` does.

Comment: While you certainly can convert an array to a string (really depends on its values), the question is: Why?

Comment: I need to replace the , with new line, was assuming making a string is easiest way. from there I can just use replace method, I think?

Comment: It seems like you just want `optionTexts.join('\n')` or `optionTexts.join('<br>')`.

Comment: @FelixKling oh, yeah that definitely is a lot cleaner. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And it's true, array doesn't have any split method. You're messing Join and Split methods, one belong to array, the other to string functions.

What you want is:

```
var splitText = optionTextString.join(",");
```

Comment: `optionTextString` should be `optionText`.